# Gradle Jar works as intended, but Gradle Run fails

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, jar

I recently wanted to build jars of my JavaFX project with Gradle. So I went ahead and created the wrapper in my project directory and edited my build.gradle file to the below.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['/']
mainClassName = "Main"

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.8'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': '../',
                'Main-Class': 'Main'
        )
    }

    from('/') {
        include 'images/**/*.png'
        include 'images/**/*.jpg'
        include 'styles/css/**/*.css'
        include 'fonts/**/*.TTF'
        include 'fonts/**/*.ttf'
    }
}
```

Using this, my compiled jar works as intended. No errors. But whenver I run `gradlew run`I get the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at styles.java.TitleStyles.<init>(TitleStyles.java:9)
        at scenes.TitleScene.<init>(TitleScene.java:34)
        at scenes.SceneController.<clinit>(SceneController.java:6)
        ... 14 more
```

The code in question is

```
private String stylesheet = this.getClass().getResource("/styles/css/TitleStyles.css").toExternalForm();
```

and my project structure looking like this

Project Structure Picture

[image]

Project Structure Picture #2

[image]

Any ideas on why I'm unable to do `gradlew run`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a classpath issue, but there was a few more things I had to do to resolve my problems. I had to recreate my gradle project with the following structure.

```
src
  -main
  --java
  ---projectCodeHere

  --resources
  ---nonJavaFileCodeHere
```

I had to relocate my non-java code to resources, otherwise it wasn't copied along with the .class files.
And then I had to change my code to look a bit like thisP

```
private String stylesheet = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("css/ConnectionStyles.css").toExternalForm();
```

Everything worked correctly after that. It seems Gradle and IntelliJ are picky about the structure of project, and I couldn't find a "clean" solution to changing classpaths, so I ended up just reorganizing my project and am I ever the happier for it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are hitting a NullpointerException when you use gradle run is because the folder structure "/styles/...." is not in the classpath

To verify this .. you can ad this line in your Main.java :

> System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path")) ;

and run it as both java -jar 
and gradle run
and you will see the difference.
Tp solve this , use the standard gradle java folder structure :

> ```
> src 
>    - main
>    --- java
>    --- resources
> ```

Comment: you could atleast accept my answer as I mentioned the right structure for a gradle project also.